# what does "ValueError: x and y must not be None"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find the integral of a function f(z) between two points using this code:

```
  z = np.linspace(0,1,100)
def f(z): 
  return z**2
times = 2000

x=np.random.rand(times)
y=np.random.rand(times)

under = y <= x**2
N1 = np.cumsum(under)
N1_over_N = (N1/np.arange(1,times + 1, dtype=np.float))
def integral(arr):
  (1-0)*(f(1)-f(0))*arr


fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1.set_size_inches(5, 5)

plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize = 1)
plt.plot(integral(N1_over_N) )
plt.show()
```

I keep getting "ValueError: x and y must not be None". I don't know what this means and I cant find reference to it anywhere. Can you help please?
Thanks

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback. We don't want to try and guess what line triggered the error.

Comment: Your integral function does not return anything... Perhaps some return would help? Otherwise you try to plot None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function integral is missing a return statement:

```
def integral(arr)
   return (1-0)*(f(1)-f(0))*arr
```

that should get you your plot.
The function though, at the moment is not doing much (1 * 1 * arr), you may want to look at the scipy integrate functions.